# How to properly load 3rd party library with wasm dependency into nuxt js project

Tags: nuxt.js, cardano

I'm trying to use this 3rd party library in my nuxtjs web app: [cardano-wallet-interface](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/cardano-wallet-interface)

This library in turn has a dependency that contains a wasm file and I couldn't get it to load properly.

I've read that I'm supposed to provide the "experiments" property of webpack config. But I'm getting errors when I tried to change my nuxt.config.js to the following:

```
export default {
    ...
    build: {
        transpile: ['cardano-wallet-interface'],
        extend(config, { isClient }) {
            if (isClient) {
                config.experiments = {
                    asyncWebAssembly: true,
                    syncWebAssembly: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
```

I have also tried this older solution described [here](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-webassembly-1a09e38d0389) to no avail:

```
export default {
    ...
    build: {
        transpile: ['cardano-wallet-interface'],
        extend(config, { isClient }) {
            if (isClient) {
                config.module.rules.push({
                    test: /\.wasm$/,
                    loaders: ['wasm-loader']
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How are we supposed to properly load wasm into our nuxt project?

using Nuxt 2.15.8 with Vue 2.6.14.